# Entity Framework - Join and populate fields from multiple tables into one object

Tags: entity-framework, join

Basic question here for which I can't find a satisfying answer. I think others coming from Stored Procedure Land will have a similar question:

What is the recommended method for joining two tables on a key and selecting fields from BOTH tables into the result set? I'd settle for a read-only result set, but it would be cooler if it was a fully EF-enabled object. (Or am I conceptually obsolete and I should adapt to "1 table 1 class"?)

Finally, does the approach change based on doing Code-First vs. Database-First?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research using *C# 5.0 In a Nutshell* and experimental testing, there is no standard (or semi-standard) way to do more than get a read-only result set.

Yes you can **project** your query into whatever floats your boat. But you CAN NOT get Entity Framework to save that object back for you, regardless of code-first or database-first approach. You *could* get out your machete and head off on your own past the ominous signpost:

```
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
```

but that's hardly appropriate for production code.

If you really want an object that does this, you can write one yourself - an intermediate class that provides a facade to the underlying tables. Obviously, this is a time investment, so I'd only do it for tables that are used in composition frequently.

For completeness, Here's how you do a projection into a strongly typed object (p.345):

```
class TempProjectionItem
{
  //define your properties
}
var temp = from n in names
 select new TempProjectionItem
 {
   Original = n,
   Vowelless = n.Replace("a","")
 };
```

The result is of type IEnumerable, which can be subsequently queried or consumed. While the example is simplistic, you can also set the object properties to any Entity object property of the same type, so it works for what I'm asking.

PS- I did find this MSDN page describing how to set up the holy grail, but when I followed the instructions I got nonsensical compiler errors and eventually gave up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716698(v=vs.100).aspx